# button skin not showing up with addElement();

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flash-cs5

I created a class in actionscritpt that extends the spark.components.Button, as I will be loading a bunch of buttons at runtime. I have a SkinnableContainer.mxml file that the spark buttons will be loaded into. When I use the addElement() method within that mxml file like so my custom skin for my button does not show.

```
//in the SkinnableContainer.mxml file
public function displayButton(button:Button):void
{
     addElement(button);
}
```

however if in that same SkinnableContainer.mxml file I drop it in via

```
<mybuttons:CustomButton x="73" y="4"/>
```

the skin shows just fine.

I thought maybe since the button was being added after I had called the loadStyleDeclarations, this might be the issue, so I called the

```
  styleManager.loadStyleDeclarations(skin, true, true, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
```

after I added the button element and the button still does not skin.

Any ideas?

Comment: In the displayButton method you have your parameter typed as a Button instead of a CustomButton, are you sure a CustomButton is being passed into it?  You do not need to reload the style declarations after adding elements to the display tree, they should be applied so long as the style is registered and the component implements usage of the style.

Answer (score 0):

As shaunhusain said your method is looking for a spark Button not your CustomButton that I assume handles the skinning.

Regardless of this, inside your method you can apply your skin to the passed button using setStyle

```
public function displayButton(button:Button):void
{
  button.setStyle("skinClass", your.button.SkinClass);
  addElement(button);
}
```